# regular expression for recurring digits in python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on to replace all digits in my data source with "numbr". Some examples are

1. 1234-546-234235-1232-1242-123124 -> numbr
2. 125436 -> numbr
3. abc1231241 -> abcnumbr

I have tried using re.sub(r'(\d+[/-]*\d+)(R?)', "numbr", token) but it is not doing replacement for example 1 properly. Any ideas of what I am missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/dyA3QC/1)

```
(?:\d-\d|\d)+
```

Another alternative `(?:\d(?:-\d)?)+` can be used, but it takes 1 extra step to complete.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
1234-546-234235-1232-1242-123124
125436
abc1231241
```

#### Output

```
numbr
numbr
abcnumbr
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:\d-\d|\d)+` Match either of the following one or more times

  - `\d-\d` Match a digit, followed by a hyphen `-`, followed by a digit
  - `\d` Match a digit

The reason to use `(?:\d-\d|\d)+` instead of `[\d-]+` is so that we don't accidentally replace valid hyphenated words such that something like `my-name` becomes `mynumbrname` or `abc-1234` doesn't become `abcnumbr`, but instead `abc-numbr`